# Java object re-initialization

Tags: java, object

On a practice exam I was given a question that looked like this:

```
Deer steve = new Deer();
Deer mike = new Deer();
steve = mike;
mike = null;
steve.eatGrass();
```

When I ran this it simply ran the method, but how is it able to run the method if the object is technically now null?

Comment: Why do you think it is `null`?

Comment: The object is not be 're-initialized' but being 're-assigned', and being reassigned a different reference. Steve points to original reference given to mike and mike is thereon given a null reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse objects with variables and references.

In

```
Deer steve = new Deer();
```

`steve` is a *variable*. `new Deer()` creates a `Deer` *object* and returns a *reference* to it. That reference's value is stored in the *variable* `steve`.

When you then do

```
steve = mike;
```

you store a copy of the value stored in `mike` in `steve`.

When you then do

```
mike = null;
```

you store the `null` reference value in the variable `mike`. This does not affect the value of `steve`.

Answer (score 0):

No. These are only references. By making *mike* null, you're not nullifying/destroying/deleting the object. You're just making the reference point to nothing. The object can still be referred from the *steve* reference. However, the original object pointed by *steve* is gone, since no reference variable is pointing to it currently.